# Creating a dynamic custom proxy element in YUI3 drag

Tags: drag-and-drop, yui, yui3

I am currently trying to implement drag and drop using YUI3. My requirement is that when the user drags a particular division, the `image inside that division` must be used as a `proxy` and when I drop it a new div different from the original must be created. I wanna know how could I create a different proxy from the original division? I see a clone attribute in `ddProxy` but how can I create a different proxy?